# clicking main category shows its related sub categories

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

[concept image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LClCv.png)

I have this idea that when user clicks on the category from the top menu its going to show all the main cards (parent cards) , and then when user clicks on any of the parent cards its going to show child cards of that parent cards.

I included an image to elaborate the idea.

how can I achieve this idea with use of html-bootstrap-js-jquery.

I have used bootstrap tabs and tab pane but I struggled to make the child level.

Comment: Please _show_ us what you got so far ([mre]), instead of just telling us about it.

Comment: *how can I achieve this* with a combination of click events and showing/hiding elements based on the clicked element.

Comment: tip: get the concept working with plain / "normal" divs *first*, then move it to bootstrap tabs.  Without the basic concept working (and knowing how it works), you'll not know if you issue is with your concept or the complex intricacies of bootstrap.

Comment: Also: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  As your question is about a specific coding issue, please include your initial attempt along with relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand question correctly,
but if your goal is to show children after clicking on "Korean cars", then simply you could hide all parent cards using style.display = "none", and display children cards using style.display = "block"